# How to get Service Application Permissions in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, user-permissions

What is the best/easiest way to read Account permissions on a particular Service Application in SharePoint 2010?
Currently I have been messing around with:

```
    var solution = SPFarm.Local.Solutions["Service App Name.wsp"];
    var solutionPermissions = solution. //trying different options here
```

I have been searching through the different options for what can follow "solution."  But so far I am at a loss.
Any ideas?

Comment: [How to Check the Permissions of a Service Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462209/how-to-check-the-permissions-of-a-service-application)  Is very similar to my predicament

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from [How to check the permissions of a Service Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462209/how-to-check-the-permissions-of-a-service-application) may be useful to you:

```
foreach (SPService service in SPFarm.Local.Services)
{
    if (service.Name.Equals("ServiceName"))
    {
        foreach (SPServiceApplication serviceApp in service.Applications)
        {
            //This gets the service app administrators
            SPCentralAdministrationSecurity serviceAppSecurity = serviceApp.GetAdministrationAccessControl();
            SPAcl<SPCentralAdministrationRights> adminAcl = serviceAppSecurity.ToAcl();

            foreach (SPAce<SPCentralAdministrationRights> rights in adminAcl)
            {
                //Handle users
            }

            //This gets the users that can invoke the service app
            SPIisWebServiceApplication webServiceApp = (SPIisWebServiceApplication) app;
            SPIisWebServiceApplicationSecurity webServiceAppSecurity = webServiceApp.GetAccessControl();
            SPAcl<SPIisWebServiceApplicationRights> invokerAcl = webServiceAppSecurity.ToAcl();

            foreach (SPAce<SPIisWebServiceApplicationRights> rights in invokerAcl)
            {
                //Handle users
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this via PowerShell. You could run a script from your code and try to interact with the permissions that way.

See this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/spweb/archive/2011/04/13/configure-service-application-permissions-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell.aspx

And how to run PowerShell from your code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C