# How to check the permissions of a Service Application?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to check and see if a specific user has permissions on a specific Service Application, but I'm not having much luck.  So far, I have managed to check if the current user has permissions with code similar to the following:

```
SPCentralAdministrationSecurity security = serviceApp.GetAdministrationAccessControl();
var acl = security.ToAcl();
bool hasAccess = acl.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPCentralAdminRights.FullControl);
```

However, like I said, I need to check the permission of a specific user, not necessarily the current user.  Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Edit:

I somehow didn't realize that acl was actually a list.  I looped through it to find the administrators for the service application, which is half the battle!  But I still need to find the accounts listed under Permissions to see which accounts have access to invoke the service app.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Service Application Permissions in SharePoint 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410481/how-to-get-service-application-permissions-in-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I've found an answer!  Here's the detailed code:

```
foreach (SPService service in SPFarm.Local.Services)
{
    if (service.Name.Equals("ServiceName"))
    {
        foreach (SPServiceApplication serviceApp in service.Applications)
        {
            //This gets the service app administrators
            SPCentralAdministrationSecurity serviceAppSecurity = serviceApp.GetAdministrationAccessControl();
            SPAcl<SPCentralAdministrationRights> adminAcl = serviceAppSecurity.ToAcl();

            foreach (SPAce<SPCentralAdministrationRights> rights in adminAcl)
            {
                //Handle users
            }

            //This gets the users that can invoke the service app
            SPIisWebServiceApplication webServiceApp = (SPIisWebServiceApplication) app;
            SPIisWebServiceApplicationSecurity webServiceAppSecurity = webServiceApp.GetAccessControl();
            SPAcl<SPIisWebServiceApplicationRights> invokerAcl = webServiceAppSecurity.ToAcl();

            foreach (SPAce<SPIisWebServiceApplicationRights> rights in invokerAcl)
            {
                //Handle users
            }
        }
    }
}
```